# Connection and testing of SQLite with ionic framework

Tags: android, sqlite, ionic-framework

hello I am working on an android project i was trying to connect to a prepopulated SQLite database on my windows machine..but im unable to go about it.
I also want to know if i can test on windows machine  or it is necessary to connect to a android device to test because im not able to see any output on the emulator.
Please help .Thanks

```
enter code here

     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-  scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic DataBase</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content ng-controller="ExampleController">
          <button class="button" ng-click="SelectAll()">select</button>
          <button class="button" ng-click="insert()">INSERT</button>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>

enter code here
```

app.js

```
var example = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
var db = null;
example.run(function ($ionicPlatform,$cordovaSQLite) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
            if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
            }
            if (window.StatusBar) {
                StatusBar.styleDefault();
            }
            //window.Plugin.sqlDB.copy("newdata.db"), function ()
            {
                db = $cordovaSQLite.openDatabase("newdata.db");

            //}, function (error) {
                db = $cordovaSQLite.openDatabase("newdata.db");

            }
        });
    });

example.controller("ExampleController", function ($scope, $cordovaSQLite) {
    $scope.SelectAll = function() {
        var query = "select ID, Dept from Department";
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []).then(function (res) {
            if (res.rows.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {

                }
            }
            console.log("selected-> " + res.rows.item(i).ID + " " + res.rows.item(i).Dept);

        }, function (err) {
            console.error("No result found");
        });
    }
});
example.controller("ExampleController", function($scope, $cordovaSQLite) {
    $scope.insert = function (Dept) {
        var query = "INSERT INTO Department (Dept) VALUES (Finance)";
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [Dept]).then(function (res) {
            console.log("INSERT ID -> " + res.insertId);
        }, function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
    }
});
```

above is the code used in my project.

Answer (score 0):

cordoba-sqlite-storage doesn't support using an existing database.  You need: https://github.com/litehelpers/cordova-sqlite-ext

run the following in your project's folder:

```
ionic plugin remove cordova-sqlite-storage 
ionic plugin add cordova-sqlite-ext
```

Comment: You should edit your answer, you typed "Cordoba" instead of "Cordova"